# How does the Doctor know what the flesh is thinking in The Almost People?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Almost People*, there are

> two Doctors

and they are pretending to be each other. When one pushes Amy up against the wall and says what the flesh is thinking and what it needs, etc., how can he know what the flesh wants

> when he’s the actual Doctor and not the flesh Doctor?

I know he was able to read the flesh in the first episode, but then he was physically touching it with his hand. And

> the flesh Doctor isn’t a Time Lord,

so he can’t make a psychic link — for that to happen they need to be touching.

Comment: I don't really remember that the two [spoiler] persons were pretending to be each other. They just were.

Comment: they where pretending to be each other they had different shoes and they swapped because the spoliers wanted to scan it learn about it to block a signal and also make sure there was no difference at all between them

Comment: No, they just swapped shoes because it was convenient, not because they were trying to fool people.

Answer (score 5):

This wouldn't be the first time in Doctor Who that memories and knowledge are transferred from a fake copy of a person to the real person they're copying.

- Take the plastic Auton version of Rory Williams, for instance. From the episode *The Big Bang*, the real Rory remembers:

  > "It's the Doctor. How did we forget the Doctor? **I was plastic.** He was the stripper at my stag. Long story."

  See also [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24030/31394).
- Then there's Queen Elizabeth I and her Zygon clone in the 50th anniversary special *The Day of the Doctor*. After killing the Zygon version of her, she seems to have suddenly acquired an awful lot of knowledge about the Zygons' plans and goals, enough indeed to fool the other Zygons:

  > ELIZABETH: The Zygons lost their own world. It burnt in the first days of the Time War. A new home is required.
  >   [...]
  >   ZYGON: Commander, why are these creatures here?
  >   ELIZABETH: Because I say they should be.
  >   [...]
  >   DOCTOR 10: And do you know why I know that you're a fake? Because you're such a bad copy. It's not just the smell, or the unconvincing hair, or the atrocious teeth, or the eyes just a bit too close together, or the breath that could stun a horse. It's because my Elizabeth, the real Elizabeth, would never be stupid enough to reveal her own plan. Honestly, why would you do that?
  >   ELIZABETH: Because it's not my plan. And I am the real Elizabeth. [...] My twin is dead in the forest. I am accustomed to taking precautions.

So the real Doctor receiving memories from the flesh Doctor isn't that much of a stretch. Basically, this is something **the showrunners aren't too careful about explaining properly** - as with many things in a show so loosely defined as Doctor Who.

Comment: yeah i thought the answer would jus be "because its doctor who" but that info has made me think